# Why does Red Hat promote CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, rhel

I recently read [this](https://danielmiessler.com/study/fedora_redhat_centos/) blog post about the relationship between Fedora, RHEL and CentOS. It is for me easy to understand why an enterprise may chooose RHEL/CentOS instead of Fedora (and why it makes sense in Red Hat business model) but more complicated between the later two although I found [some good arguments](http://linuxpitstop.com/rhel-vs-centos/). Is CentOS just a copy of RHEL? In addition of being open source, which license has RHEL that allows this copy to be legal and how does it fit into Red Hat business model? A layman explanation would be very appreciated.

Comment: Note that that blog post is not very well worded and is not anything close to official. Among other things, the company is "Red Hat", not "Redhat", and the Linux distribution is "Red Hat Enterprise Linux", not (again) "Redhat".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, CentOS was able to be distributed before Red Hat took them over by removing the things that Red Hat had a non-free license on.  Typically this was documentation, images, etc. and not the actual code.  So the CentOS team was able to rebuild RPMs, etc. using the exact source, but slightly different images, etc.

No mind reading as to why Red Hat allowed CentOS to continue... and so this is going opinion based (not good but it is what it is).

Basically, Fedora ISN'T a replacement for Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).  It contains beta features, etc.  Whereas CentOS is as close as possible to the real deal.

Now, there are plenty of organisations who need to be able to run RHEL to support other software (i.e., you can't get support for ProductX from CompanyY unless you are running it on a Red Hat system) but they can either support in-house, or it is for testing, etc. and so they can't justify the price for a real Red Hat license/install/support contract.   BUT if Red Hat can get these organisations to use CentOS as a drop-in replacement, one day they *will* be able to justify spending the $ on a support contract, etc. and so it would be easier to convert a non-paying user of your product to be a paying user of your product  versus trying to get a group to move from say Debian or one of the BSDs to RHEL.

Comment: Any linux distro seeking community adoption darn well better have a free offering, not just for amateurs, but also for docker and for ephemeral cloud hosts whose life span is minutes, hours, or days.  Licensing these systems would be cumbersome and since they're so short lived, support typically isn't very important.